# Як назвати того, хто завжди перетворює все в змагання, по-англійськи назвиається сompetitive person

Tags: переклад, синоніми, прикметники, одним-словом

Я вже пів години сиджу і не можу згадати слова, яке обозначає людину, що перетворює будь-яку справу, чи зайняття в змагання, будь то прибирання чи сортування речей.

В англійській мові таку людину можна було б назвати competitive, але саме того слова яке мені потрібно в його перекладах найти не можу.

Найближче українське слово до того що мені потрібно це "змагальницький" - що безумовно не те, і ще й звучить погано.

Як би ви назвали того, кому завжди потрібно бути кращим від інших в усьому, хто буде змагатися навіть в тому, хто бистріше найде пару до шкарпетки?

Comment: На вікі є стаття [Змаговий аналіз](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Змаговий_аналіз_(онлайн_алгоритм)) як відповідник [Competitive analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Competitive_analysis_(online_algorithm)).

Comment: Закомплексована людина я б назвав. :) Той чи та, кому треба постійно собі доводити, що вони вартують того методом приниження інших через змагання.

Comment: Я би переклав як [_суперницька_](https://goroh.pp.ua/Тлумачення/суперницький) [_особа_].